# Making a simple table Using D3 in meteor

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I am testing d3.js in meteor.
While trying to make a simple table for test,I met a trouble.

Here is my codes

```
<template name="ob">
    <h4>Table test- {{name}}</h4>
    <svg id="obTable"><table><tr></tr></table></svg>
</template>
```

And below is javascript file for template above...

```
Template.ob.onRendered(function() {
    //Width and height
    var w = 600;
    var h = 350;

    //Define key function, to be used when binding data
    var key = function (d) {
        return d.index;
    };

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("#obTable")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var dataset = require('../data/ob.json');
    // var dataset = Bars.find({}).fetch();


    //Select…
    var table = svg.selectAll('table').append('table')
        .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
        .style("border", "2px black solid");
    // .data(dataset, key);

    console.log(table);

    var rows = table.selectAll('tr')
        .data(dataset, key)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

    console.log(rows);

    rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d){ console.log(d); return d;} )
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .text(function(d) {console.log("here"); return d;})
        .style("border", "1px black solid")
        .style("padding", "10px")
        .style("font-size","12px");
});
```

I've got no errors from those code above, but when I execute my app, I could not see any table or table contents. ( since I can see in  contents well, I am sure there is no problem on showing template itself)

Things that I can't most understand is that I can see log messages from `rows.selectAll('td').data(function(d){ console.log(d); return d;} )` well, but I can't see any log from `.text(function(d) {console.log("here"); return d;})`
I doubt this could be a reason for not showing table, but could not solve further.

I installed d3 from npm and it's version is 4.10.0

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your `dataset` looks like?

Comment: just simple json array like 
`[
  { "date" : "2013-01-01", "close" : 45 },
  { "date" : "2013-02-01", "close" : 50 },
  { "date" : "2013-03-01", "close" : 55 },
  { "date" : "2013-04-01", "close" : 50 },
  { "date" : "2013-05-01", "close" : 45 },
  { "date" : "2013-06-01", "close" : 50 },
  { "date" : "2013-07-01", "close" : 50 },
  { "date" : "2013-08-01", "close" : 55 }
]`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. Issue is that the dom is getting rewritten due to reactive updates, and your on render select is getting destroyed.

How I solved this was to do a template helper at the end of the template. Something like this...

```
    <template name="ob">
        <h4>Table test- {{name}}</h4>
        <svg id="obTable"><table><tr></tr></table></svg>

        {{doD3Stuff}}

    </template>

    Template.ob.helpers(function() {
        doD3Stuff: function() {
        // all your on render code here
        //Width and height
        var w = 600;
        var h = 350;

        //Define key function, to be used when binding data
        var key = function (d) {
        return d.index;
        };

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("#obTable")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

        var dataset = require('../data/ob.json');
        // var dataset = Bars.find({}).fetch();


        //Select…
        var table = svg.selectAll('table').append('table')
        .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
        .style("border", "2px black solid");
        // .data(dataset, key);

        console.log(table);

        var rows = table.selectAll('tr')
        .data(dataset, key)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

        console.log(rows);

        rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d){ console.log(d); return d;} )
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .text(function(d) {console.log("here"); return d;})
        .style("border", "1px black solid")
        .style("padding", "10px")
        .style("font-size","12px");
    }
```